# finding if certain numbers are don't cares in KMAP

Tags: circuit-design, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

i've solved several question but i don't know how to solve this one, please help me if you can, as my due date is today.

\$f(a,b,c,d)=\sum(0,1,2,4,5,10,12)\$

after a lot of trials, i know that this is the boolean i get a'c'+c'd'+b'd'

how can i know if (i) 6 AND 14 (ii) 15 could've some of the don't cares?

this is important: how can i know for sure if 8 was a don't care? (if it was).

please help me if you know the answer and can help. i am so frustrated from this.

this is what i got, please tell me if its true and if not help me correct it:

```
 c'.d' c'.d c.d c.d'
```

a'.b'  1 1 0 1

a'.b 1 1 0 x

a.b  1 0 x x

a.b' x 0 0 1

if m6, and m14 together, i get cd' which is not what i was looking for so i guess it's not possible.
if m15, it doesn't help me at all (it's not connected to anything, i can't pair it)
if m8, if i am right, then it simplifies the simplification of the given function. i am not sure if it is a must though

Comment: Draw a truth table - it might help you.

Comment: tried so, but i am not sure whether 8 must be a no care, and if 15 was a don't care :(

Comment: Well draw it in your question!

Comment: i've added it and elaborated my efforts